# cannot install required dependencies into my Conda environment

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, flask, keras, imutils

the command I typed is "python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt".

I think the first error is that the library mkl_rt is missing but I'm not sure how to add.

Complete log:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting Flask==1.1.1
  Using cached Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting imutils==0.5.3
  Using cached imutils-0.5.3.tar.gz (17 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting Keras==2.4.0
  Using cached Keras-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (170 kB)
Collecting opencv-python==4.4.0.46
  Using cached opencv-python-4.4.0.46.tar.gz (88.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4837 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.9"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-63.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Collecting scikit-build
        Using cached scikit_build-0.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
      Collecting cmake
        Using cached cmake-3.24.0-py2.py3-none-macosx_10_10_universal2.macosx_10_10_x86_64.macosx_11_0_arm64.macosx_11_0_universal2.whl (77.9 MB)
      Collecting pip
        Using cached pip-22.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
      Collecting numpy==1.17.3
        Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting distro
        Using cached distro-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
      Collecting packaging
        Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
      Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2
        Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [4428 lines of output]
            Running from numpy source directory.
            blas_opt_info:
            blas_mkl_info:
            customize UnixCCompiler
              libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib', '/usr/lib']
              NOT AVAILABLE



..............
```

For now I'm going to try to install the requirements with out the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when there is a problem between the versions of python and /or pip vs the versions of the packages you're trying to install.

If you know the version of python used to generate the `requirements.txt` file that you have, please make sure to use the same version. Otherwise try upgrading the version of python.

Comment: The problem was that it was not my requirements.txt, so then I went and searched how to generate one. Couple errors later, im on the right track. Thank you!